# NodeJS jsPDF addImage gives an error when adding a PNG

Tags: node.js, typescript, png, jspdf

I am not entirely sure what is wrong. I am just trying to add a PNG image and this library refuses to work. I have had to do way too much just to get this library to still not work and I may have to move to another library, but before I do that I wanted to ask the question. My code is below.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as PNG from 'png-js';
import * as atob from 'atob';
import * as btoa from 'btoa';

export interface Global extends NodeJS.Global {
    window: any;
    navigator: any;
    btoa: any;
    atob: any;
    PNG: any;
}

declare var global: Global;
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => ({})}};
global.navigator = {};
global.btoa = btoa;
global.atob = atob;
global.PNG = PNG;

import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf/dist/jspdf.node.debug';

export class PDFGenerator {

    constructor() {
    }

    public async generatePDF(): void {
       const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3');
       const image = fs.readFileSync('src/assets/images/logo.png');
       const width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
       doc.addImage(image.toString('base64'), 'PNG', (width / 2), 0);
       const data = doc.output();
       fs.writeFileSync(`public/reports/test-report.pdf`, data);

   }
}
```

When I run this, the PDF is printed with only text and I get `error: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined` and `fn is not a function`.  I have traced this to a function called `decodePixels().buffer`. This looks like a bug in the code, but since nobody seems to have complained about it, I assume I'm doing something wrong.  Any type of help would really be appreciated.